# gitlab automatically cleanup code and make a commit

Tags: git, automation, gitlab

**Context:**
I am using git and gitlab regularly and we use gitlab-CI to perform checks.

This works quite well. One of the steps (for a python project) is to perform coding style checks.

- check that there are no tab characters
- check, that line endings are all in unix format and not in dos / mac format
- perform flake8 checks

**Problem:**
replacing tab characters with spaces and converting dos line endings into unix line endings are
rather stupid tasks, which can easily automated.

What I wonder is. Is there any way, that gitlab could (after an push or at least for any merge request) not only check, whether tabs / line endings are OK, but if necessary modify files and create a new commit on the given branch / MR?

So is there a way to make a CI step, that updates a branch? Is there any other automation step  hook on gitlab, that would allow desired task?

I am aware, that this could be done  client side with pre-commit hooks or alike, but I cannot ensure, that all developers have the hooks installed and that in particular their hooks are up to date and that their environment has all the dependencies to execute these scripts.

Thus I'm really looking for a server side solution

Comment: You can do this locally with git hooks.

Comment: we are over 20 developpers and I can't force all of them easily to install hooks and maintain and upgrade them, therefore I'm looking for a server side solution

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to do this.  By default, GitLab's CI tokens are read-only, so you'll have to add a token for a user with suitable permissions into the secret store and use that.  You can use an arbitrary token from the environment by using a command like the following:

```
git -c credential.helper='!f(){echo username=$USERNAME; echo password=$TOKEN;};f' \
    push origin
```

*However*, this is generally not the recommended practice.  Typically the practice is to have your CI system check this but not fix it, and then to provide an easy-to-use script that fixes all of these things.  If your developers are in the habit of writing sane, logical commits, they won't appreciate a fixup commit being dropped on top.  Additionally, pushing a commit to the branch will kick off another CI job, meaning that if you ever fail to reach a stable state, you'll kick off unending CI jobs.

A script to fix the line endings and tabs is as simple as this (assuming you don't have people using the legacy Mac OS 9 CR line endings and don't have binary files):

```
#!/bin/sh

git ls-files | xargs perl -pi -e 's/\t/    /g; s/\r//g;'
```

Any system with a full Git implementation will necessarily have Perl available and no additional commands are required.

Since `flake8` doesn't currently provide an autofix option, you will necessarily have to have developers manually fix those errors anyway.